# Mounting Airport TimeCapsule on Synology with spaces

Tags: nas, smb, synology, cifs, time-capsule

I'm trying to mount my Airport Time Capsule on my Synology DS916+ NAS. However, it is not working for a directory that has a space in it.

There are two folders on the TC "Data" and "User Name". I can mount the former but not the latter. Instead I get an error message "Failed to connect to the remote folder".

AFP does it this way:

```
$ mount 
//User%20Name@My%60s%20AirPort%20Time%20Capsule._afpovertcp._tcp.local/User%20Name on /Volumes/User Name-1 (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by username)
```

I couldn't get this working using the web interface. It appears that the it is a space in the directory that is to blame as I can mount the 'data' directory with that user without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get this working using the web interface - but I could with the command line:

1. SSH into the NAS
2. Mount the share using CIFS/SMB

   ```
   mount.cifs user='User Name',password='pass123',sec=ntlm,uid=1000 //My-AirPort-Time-Capsule.local /media/data
   ```

Where `uid=1000` is the UID of the local user that you the files to be owned by.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem when trying to mount my Time Capsule's "Data" directory to my Synology NAS. The key was to use the correct syntax order for the mount.cifs command.

`sudo mount.cifs //10.0.0.1/Data /volume1/TimeCapsule -o user=username123,password=password123,sec=ntlm,uid=1000`